# Why won't IntelliSense work with pandas pipe()?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

In VScode, it seems that Intellisense is not able to infer the return type of calls to `pandas.DataFrame.pipe`. It is a source of some inconvenience as I cannot rely on autocompletion after using pipe. But I haven't seen this issue mentioned anywhere, so it makes me wonder if it's just me or if I am missing something.

This is what I do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]})
df2 = df.pipe(lambda x: x + 1)
```

VSCode recognizes `df` as a DataFrame: [image], but has no clue what `df2` might be: [image]

A first thought would be that this is due to the lack of type hinting in the lambda function. But if I try this instead:

```
def add_one(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  return df + 1
df3 = df.pipe(add_one)
```

Still IntelliSense can't guess the type of `df3`: [image]

Of course as a last recourse I can add a hint to `df3` itself:

```
df3: pd.DataFrame = df.pipe(add_one)
```

But it seems like it shouldn't be necessary. IntelliSense seems very capable of inferring return types in other complex scenarios, such as involving `map`: [image]

---

UPDATE:

I experimented a bit more and found some interesting patterns which narrow down the range of possible causes.

I am not sufficiently familiar with Pylance to really understand why this is happening, but here is what I find:

**Finding 1**

It is happening to pandas.core.common.pipe if import it. (I know pd.DataFrame.pipe calls pandas.core.generic.pipe, but that internally calls pandas.core.common.pipe, and I can reproduce the issue in pandas.core.common.pipe.)
[image]

**Finding 2**

If I copy the definition of that same function from pandas.core.common, together with the relevant imports of Callable and TypeVar, and declare `T` as `TypeVar('T')`, IntelliSense actually does its magic.
[image]

(Actually in pandas.core.common, `T` is not defined as `TypeVar('T')` but imported from pandas._typing, where it is defined as `TypeVar('T')`. If I import it instead of defining it myself, it still works fine.)

From this I am tempted to conclude that pandas does everything right, but that Pylance is failing to keep track of type information for some unknown reason...

**Finding 3**

If I just copy pandas.core.common into a local file pandascommon.py and import pipe from that, it works fine too!
[image]

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: I have just reproduced it on python 3.8.10 and pandas 1.3.5, but I have come across this issue on a range of machines and a range of versions for python and pandas...

I have experimented a bit more since this morning, and my suspicions are now on Pylance rather than pandas. I'll write it up a bit more properly tomorrow but it looks like the type annotations of pipe are not correctly imported, perhaps (to be checked) because pylance is not importing typing.Callable and typing.Typevar for the relevant pandas submodules...

Comment: @richardec as mentioned yesterday I updated my question with some additional experiments, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

It was due to the stubs shipped with Pylance. Specifically in `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.3.2/dist/bundled/stubs/pandas/`.

For example in core/common.pyi I found this stub:
`def pipe(obj, func, *args, **kwargs): ...`

Pylance uses this instead of the annotations in `pandas.core.common.pipe`, causing the issue.

One heavy-handed solution is to just erase (or rename) the pandas stubs in that folder. Then pipe works again. On the other hand, it breaks some other things, for example read_csv is no longer correctly inferred to return a DataFrame. I think the better long run solution would be for the Pylance maintainers to improve those stubs...

A minimally invasive solution to the original `pipe` issue is to edit `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.3.2/dist/bundled/stubs/pandas/core/frame.pyi` in the following manner:

- add `from pandas._typing import T`
- replace the line starting with `def pipe` by:

  `def pipe(self, func: Callable[..., T], *args, **kwargs) -> T: ...`

Answer (score 1):

I also simulated in vscode and found that this problem does exist. I think it may be related to the return value definition in the pipe () method. I submit the problem on GitHub and hope to gain something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question with new findings which make me suspect that the issue might be with Pylance rather than pandas...